# How can I deploy code changes in AWS in a CircleCI 1.0 project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, circleci

CircleCI is requiring everyone to migrate to version 2.0 of their configuration format, but I have not had time to move away. I plan to migrate away from the platform anyway, so I do not now wish to migrate to 2.0.

Even after the EOL of 1.0, I was still able to deploy minor code changes, which was all that was necessary to maintain my system at this time.

However, a minor code change I tried to deploy earlier this week failed.

I don't want to migrate to 2.0, but want to deploy the code change (it's 2 lines).

I'm using Github and deploying to AWS.

How I can "circumvent" CircleCI to push this minor code change in Github to AWS?

Answer (score 2):

The 1.0 version was officially "sunsetted" on August 31st, 2018, but I think they might have unofficially given an extension to folks still on 1.0, and it is only now fully being turned off. However, 2.0 has been available for more than a year now, which should have been long enough to do the migration.

My experience of CircleCI support is that if you have a bug, they will help on their forum. Paying customers can log a ticket (and that is a more reliable way to contact them). Of course, if your support issue is to re-enable 1.0, or to do the migration for you, then you do not have a reasonable request.

The trade-off with hosted CI, which will have saved you maintenance time and costs over the long term, is that sometimes migrations will be necessary. Engineering teams should schedule upgrade time into their diary so that these things can be tackled in good time.

### Direct answer

For your deployment now, I suggest you run your tests locally and deploy from a development machine. After that, I would suggest upgrading to 2.0 (or move to a different provider) is a high priority for your team.

In other words, I do not believe there is a way in which you can do a deployment using a 1.0 configuration file. However, if you won't move to 2.0, and you do not wish to do a deployment from your own dev machine, you could try asking tech support whether you (or they) can do a special 1.0 run. It is conceivable they still have the capacity to do so.